# Upper bound of two binomially distributed random variables

Tags: limits, statistics, random-variables, upper-lower-bounds, fake-proofs

Let be $X_1,X_2$ two i.i.d binomially distributed random variables, where $p$ is the probability of success and $m$ the length of the underlying Bernoulli experiment. In a proof our professor argues
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P\left(\left|\frac{X_1+X_2}{n}\right|\geq \epsilon\right)=0,
$$
because of *Chebyshev's inequality*.

---

I don't understand why she needs *Chebyshev's inequality* and how we could apply it here?
We know that $X_1,X_2$ are both bounded by $m$, so
\begin{align*}
P\left(\left|\frac{X_1+X_2}{n}\right|\geq \epsilon\right)\leq P\left(\left|\frac{2m}{n}\right|\geq \epsilon\right).
\end{align*}
Hence, for all $n\geq \frac{m}{\epsilon}$ the inequality $\left|\frac{2m}{n}\right|\geq \epsilon$ is never true so that $P\left(\left|\frac{2m}{n}\right|\geq \epsilon\right)=0$. This means that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P\left(\left|\frac{2m}{n}\right|\geq \epsilon\right)=0$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: My guess:  There is some connection between m and n.

Comment: @herbsteinberg, no there isn't.

Comment: I agree Chebyshev's inequality seems unnecessary, since $|X_1+X_2|$ is bounded by a constant.

Comment: @user51547 even if $|X_1+X_2|$ wasn't bounded I don't see how Chebyshev's inequality would help/could be applied?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. Maybe they meant Markov's inequality (using the second moment)? Seems easier to apply here.

Comment: @user51547, yes maybe the professor had Markov's inequality in mind. Using the first moment/expected value, we get $$P\left(\left|\frac{X_1+X_2}{n}\right|\geq \epsilon\right)=P\left(\left|X_1+X_2\right|\geq n\epsilon\right)\underset{\text{Markov}}{\leq}\frac{\mathbb{E}(X_1+X_2)}{n\epsilon}.$$